# Download of a file in Java from URL via HttpEntity and IOUtils - An infinite loop?

Tags: java, download, inputstream, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-commons-io

I use some Apache Commons libraries. In particular, I'm using version 4.2.5 of `httpclient` and version 2.4 of `commons-io`. Thus, using a [`DefaultHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) I try to download pdf files from URLs. E.g. Suppose that I want to download this file: http://www.lowaste.it/files/pdf/C12-02_filiere.pdf. I get a 200 response, but as one may see by using a browser, the file is never loaded. It seems that the bytes are never loaded after the first answer.

In my code, I do as follows:

```
HttpEntity entity =//... I get the entity via DefaultHttpClient
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
FileOutputStream out = // init the OutputStream
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

The function `IOUtils.copy` seems to loops infinitely and never stops. I stayed ours waiting for the file to be saved.
The `IOUtils.copy` function uses [`IOUtils.copyLarge`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29). I report the function for the sake of completeness:

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output, byte[] buffer)
        throws IOException {
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I also tried to replace `IOUtils.copy(in, out)` with:

```
IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(in), out);
```

since object `in` relies on a  network connection, but it doesn't helped!

Any idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: The only solution that I found is to use a Timer that closes the streams after a period (e.g. 5 minutes). I only have to handle the `NullPointerException` eventually thrown by `copyLarge`. However, this solution seems to be a little tricky!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should use `HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout()` to set read/write timeout for the socket. For watchdog the solution is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9873902/267197).